# Which logical fallacy is this: A is a C, B is a C, therefore A is a B?

Tags: logic, syllogism

Does this kind of logical fallacy have a name?

```
Apples are fruit.
Oranges are fruit.
Therefore, apples are oranges.
```

I'm guessing it's a particular kind of [statistical syllogism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_syllogism)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is the [Fallacy of the undistributed middle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallacy_of_the_undistributed_middle):

> All Apples are Fruit
>
> All Oranges are Fruit
>
> > Therefore, all Apples are Oranges

is clearly invalid.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that is the fallacy of undistributed middle.  The middle or shared term or class, "fruit", remains undistributed in either premise.  For a more complete discussion of this fallacy, you could take a look at [this brief introduction](https://philosophy.lander.edu/logic/middle_fall.html).